# Command line - writing a description of a Python programm that can be called by '-help'

Tags: python, command-prompt

I have a Python program that I execute in the Command Prompt by saying python3 name.py . Everyhting works fine, but I want to create a description of the programm that can be called by the help command, e.g. help (name.py).

Is there a way to do that?  I can't find anything on the Internet!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can it be `python name.py --help`?

Comment: I get the following message:
'C:\Users\User\anaconda3\pkgs\spyder-4.0.1-py37_0\python.exe C:\Users\User\anaconda3\pkgs\spyder-4.0.1-py37_0\Scripts\spyder-script.py "C:\Users\User\.spyder-py3\python name.py"'

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for so-called "commandline parameters", handled by `argparse`, this is described under [this URL of the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html).

(For your information, I've given you the reference for the Python 3.3 version, but the other versions are very similar. In case you want to be sure to be working with the correct version, this can be done using a simple modification of the mentioned URL).

Comment: You should refrain from posting link-only answers